# Updating Item in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, singleton, adapter

I'm making a to do list app using a `RecyclerView`. When a task is clicked a dialog will appear and the user will be able to edit the name of the task. Once the user exists the dialog I want to reflect the changes of the task in the `RecyclerView`.

I have an activity called ListActivity that hosts a fragment which contains the `RecyclerView`. Likewise, I create my `AlertDialog` in a class called `EditTaskFragment`. Lastly, I store all the task objects in an `arraylist` in a `Singleton` class called `TaskLab`.

To retrieve the `String` after the user changes the name of a task item in the `RecyclerView` I am calling `onActivityResult()` in the `ListFragment` class. But I'm not sure how to update the task object that is stored in my `Singleton` and then how to get the `ViewHolder` to changes the `Title` field of a task item.

My ListFragment class

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

private static final int REQUEST_TITLE = 0;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private TaskAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.the_task_list);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    updateUI();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == ListFragment.REQUEST_TITLE) {
       // Do something.
    }

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updateUI();
}

public void updateUI() {
    List<Task> taskList = TaskLab.get(getActivity()).getTaskList();

    if(mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new TaskAdapter(taskList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }else {
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

private class TaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskHolder>{

    private List<Task> mTaskList;

    public TaskAdapter(List<Task> taskList) {

        mTaskList = taskList;
    }

    @Override
    public TaskHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.task_list_layout, parent, false);
        return new TaskHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TaskHolder holder, int position) {
        Task currentTask = mTaskList.get(position);
        holder.bindData(currentTask);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mTaskList.size();
    }
}

private class TaskHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Task mTask;
    private TextView mTaskTitle;
    private CheckBox mSolved;

    private static final String DIALOG = "edit_dialog";

    public TaskHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        mTaskTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
        mSolved = itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_solved);
    }

    public void bindData(Task task) {
        mTask = task;
        mTaskTitle.setText(mTask.getTitle());
        mSolved.setChecked(mTask.isSolved());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        EditTaskFragment dialog = EditTaskFragment.newInstance(mTask.getTitle());
        dialog.setTargetFragment(ListFragment.this, REQUEST_TITLE);
        dialog.show(manager, DIALOG);
    }
}

}
```

My EditTaskFragment class

```
public class EditTaskFragment extends DialogFragment {

private EditText mTaskTitle;
private String mTaskName;

private static final String ARG_TASK_TITLE = "task_title";
public static final String EXTRA_TASK_TITLE = "list_app_task_title";

private void sendResult(int resultCode, String taskName) {
    if(getTargetFragment() == null) {
        return;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TASK_TITLE,taskName);

    getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(),resultCode, intent);
}

public static EditTaskFragment newInstance(String taskName) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_TASK_TITLE, taskName);

    EditTaskFragment fragment = new EditTaskFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mTaskName = getArguments().getString(ARG_TASK_TITLE);
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_task_dialog, null);
    mTaskTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_task_title);
    mTaskTitle.setText(mTaskName);

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(view)
            .setTitle(R.string.edit_task_dialog_title)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.edit_task_dialog_positive, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, mTaskTitle.getText().toString());
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.edit_task_dialog_negative, null)
            .create();
}
}
```

My Singleton class - TaskLab

```
public class TaskLab {

private static TaskLab sTaskLab;
private List<Task> mTaskList;

private TaskLab(Context context){
    mTaskList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Task task = new Task();
        task.setTitle("Task #" + i);
        task.setSolved(i%2 == 0);
        mTaskList.add(task);
    }
}

public static TaskLab get(Context context) {
    if(sTaskLab == null) {
        sTaskLab = new TaskLab(context);
    }

    return sTaskLab;
}

public List<Task> getTaskList(){
    return mTaskList;
}

public Task getTask(int id){
    for(Task task : mTaskList) {
        if(task.getId().equals(id)){
            return task;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: how about instead of using the onActivityResult again why don't you just call the recyclerView and ask it to use the updated list (which I can't see that you are doing in the code). If you are updating the list then you should reinitilalize and reAttach the adapter on the recyclerView!

Comment: Have you considered passing the whole `Task` object to the fragment, so you have access to the ID? Then you could pass back the edited title and ID back to the `ListFragment`. Once the `ListFragment` knows the ID and edited title, it could update the the `List<Task>` being used in the adapter, and the `Task` in the singleton.

Answer (score 0):

In `EditTaskFragment.sendResult()` you are calling `onActivityResult()` of the target fragment. **This is wrong**. `onActivityResult()` is meant to be called by the framework, not the programmer.
What you have to do is **use the enclosing activity of the fragments in order to pass data between the fragments**.

---

1. Define an interface `TaskChangedListener`
2. Make your **activity** implement it, as well as `ListFragment`
3. In `EditTaskFragment.sendResult()`, use `((TaskChangedListener) getActivity()).onTaskChanged(taskName)`
4. In `onTaskChanged()` of the activity, you will need to find the `ListFragment` (you can find it *by tag* from the fragment manager) and then call its `onTaskChanged()` from there.
5. In `onTaskChanged()` of `ListFragment` do:

   List taskList = TaskLab.get(getActivity()).getTaskList();
   mAdapter.clear();
   mAdapter.addAll(taskList);
   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

You will need to add the `clear()` and `addAll()` methods to your `TaskAdapter` class:

```
void clear() {
    mTaskList.clear();
}

void addAll(List<Task> taskList) {
    mTaskList.addAll(taskList);
}
```

As a next step